# Pandas drop row when parse_dates fails

Tags: python, pandas

I came across a problem I thought the smart people at Pandas would've already solved, but I can't seem to find anything, so here I am.

The problem I'm having originates from some bad data, that I expected pandas would be able to filter on reading.
The data looks like this:

```
Station;Datum;Zeit;Lufttemperatur;Relative Feuchte;Wettersymbol;Windgeschwindigkeit;Windrichtung
9;12.11.2016;08:04;-1.81;86;;;
9;12.11.2016;08:19;-1.66;85.5;;;
9;²;08:34;-1.71;85.6;;;
9;12.11.2016;08:49;-1.91;87.7;;;
9;12.11.2016;09:04;-1.66;86.6;;;
```

(This is using the ISO-8859-1 character set, it looks different in UTF-8 etc.) I want to read the second column as dates, so naturally, I used

```
data = pandas.read_csv(file, sep=";", encoding="ISO-8859-1", parse_dates=["Datum"], 
                       date_parser=lambda x: pandas.to_datetime(x, format="%d.%m.%Y"))
```

which gave

```
ValueError: time data '²' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y' (match)
```

Although pandas.read_csv has an input parameter **error_bad_lines** which looks like it would help my case, it appears all it does is filter out lines that do not have the correct amount of columns. Now I can filter out this particular line in many different ways, and to my knowing all of them require to first load all the data, filter out the rows and then converting the column to datetime objects, but I'd rather do it while reading in the file. It seems to be possible since when I leave out the date_parser, the file gets parsed succesfully and the strange character is just left as it is (although that might give issues when doing datetime instructions later on).

Is there a way for pandas to filter out rows it can't use the date_parser on while reading the file instead of during post-processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `errors` parameter in [**`pandas.to_datetime`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```
date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors="coerce")
```

---

```
file = "file.csv"

data = pd.read_csv(
    file, sep=";", encoding="ISO-8859-1", parse_dates=["Datum"],
    date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors="coerce")
)

data

   Station      Datum   Zeit  Lufttemperatur  Relative Feuchte  Wettersymbol  Windgeschwindigkeit  Windrichtung
0        9 2016-12-11  08:04           -1.81              86.0           NaN                  NaN           NaN
1        9 2016-12-11  08:19           -1.66              85.5           NaN                  NaN           NaN
2        9        NaT  08:34           -1.71              85.6           NaN                  NaN           NaN
3        9 2016-12-11  08:49           -1.91              87.7           NaN                  NaN           NaN
4        9 2016-12-11  09:04           -1.66              86.6           NaN                  NaN           NaN
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! My fault for not looking into the actual date parser instead of the file reader I guess.